# Remove double dashes from url using mod_rewrite module in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a rewriteRule to fix some urls from an old webshop so to make them available within a new webshop (relaunch). This is the regex.

```
#change period to dash
RewriteRule "^(.*)/([^.]*)\.+([^.]*\..*)$" $1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule "^(.*)/([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$" $1/$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```

The idea is to convert periods in the url to a single dash.

> /Biertischhussen/Dena-Biertischhusse-3tlg.-Set-Arcade-50x220cm-ecru-lang
>
> /Biertischhussen/Dena-Biertischhusse-3tlg-Set-Arcade-50x220cm-ecru-lang

The rewriteRule only works 80% though, because it produces double dashes... How can I fix this?

> /Biertischhussen/Dena-Biertischhusse-3tlg--Set-Arcade-50x220cm-ecru-lang/

Comment: Try adding `-*` after the dot matching pattern to consume all existing `-`s after the dot. Something like `"^(.*)/([^.]*)\.+-*([^.]*\..*)$"` and `"^(.*)/([^.]*)\.-*([^.]*)$"`

Comment: thanks. this worked. feel free to make this your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a consuming `-*` pattern after `\.+`, all existing `-` symbols will get matched, and thus will get removed as a result of the replacement (since they are not captured, i.e. they are not inside `(...)`).

Use

```
 "^(.*)/([^.]*)\.+-*([^.]*\..*)$"
                  ^^
```

and

```
"^(.*)/([^.]*)\.-*([^.]*)$" 
                ^^
```